# Mimic minimize function from Python in R

Tags: python, r, excel, graph, least-squares

I have the following data points:

`xdata` looks like the following.

```
1000.00
300.00
100.00
30.00
10.00
3.00
1.00
0.30
0.10
0.03
0.01
0.00
```

`ydata` looks like the following.

```
91.8
95.3
100
123
203
620
1210
1520
1510
1520
1590
1620
```

I am running the following commands in python:

```
results = minimize(fit.dataFit,cParams,args=(xdata,np.array(ydata)))
curve = np.array(ydata)+results.residual
Std = [list(i) for i in zip(xdata,ydata, curve)]
```

My main problem is being unable to track the stream of changes to the data. `dataFit` does the following operation:

`y_model = (ymax*xdata / (ec50 + xdata)) + Ns* xdata + ymin
return y_model - ydata`

where

1. `ymax = 1624.75`
2. `ymin = 91.85`
3. `ec50 = 3`
4. `Ns = 0.2045514`

Lastly, minimize is being called from the following library:

`from lmfit import minimize,Minimizer,Parameters,Parameter,report_errors,report_fit`

The results I get for `Std` in python are:

```
110
49.1
52.4
121
299
688
1110
1420
1550
1590
1610
1620
```

I am trying to replicate the same results in **R** or in Excel. Either one will be sufficient. The problem I am having is that I unable to accurately mimic the same behavior as the `minimize` (which is minimizing least-squares) and `residual`. I have tried searching for corresponding libraries in **R** with the `minimize` and `residual` function; however, I was not able to find any(nor use it correctly) that gave me the same results as in Python.

When I graph `xdata`, `ydata`, and the results of `minimize` (which I have provided above), I get the following graph in Python. Ultimately, I would just like to reproduce this same graph in **R** or Excel. 
[image]

How to proceed? I am not an expert in Python, hence, I am not able to correctly port the code from Python to **R** or Excel.

Comment: Check out the function 'nls' in R

Comment: Hi @gabriel-f-geisler-mesevage, I apologize! I stand corrected and remove my wrong assumption. As you guessed, the listed items are the initial parameter values for the fit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate this in R using the function `nls()`. First, I set up your data so it can be read into R.

```
## Replicate results from Python `minimize` with R `nls()`
# First I load your data in
df <- data.frame(xdata = c(1000.00,300.00,100.00,30.00,10.00,3.00,1.00,0.30,
                           0.10,0.03,0.01,0.00),
                 ydata = c(91.8,95.3,100,123,203,620,1210,1520,1510,1520,1590,
                           1620))

# Now we estimate the model via nonlinear least squares
nls.fit <- nls(ydata ~ (ymax*xdata / (ec50 + xdata)) + Ns*xdata + ymin, data=df,
    start=list(ymax=1624.75, ymin = 91.85, ec50 = 3, Ns = 0.2045514))
```

I use your starting values for the parameters, although these are not the values that the model settles on. To see the parameters type `nls.fit` into the console and R will display information about the fitted model.

```
df$nls.pred <- fitted(nls.fit) # We extract the predicted values of the model
head(df) # We can examine the values of `xdata`, `ydata` and our predictions

  xdata ydata  nls.pred
1  1000  91.8 109.48985
2   300  95.3  49.02029
3   100 100.0  52.29715
4    30 123.0 120.61060
5    10 203.0 298.55367
6     3 620.0 687.63743

# We can see that the values we have obtained are very close to 
# what you obtained in the variable you named Std in python.

# I now load the ggplot2 library to recreate your plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(xdata, ydata))+geom_point(color='red')+
  geom_line(data=df, aes(xdata, nls.pred))+
  theme_classic()+ # This makes the background black and white as in your plot 
  scale_x_log10() # The axis in your post is logged
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Gabriel F Geisler Mesevage,  I gratefully appreciate your detailed reply.  It helped me in creating an interactive Std Curve plotting R Shiny app for my research purpose. . I have posted a global curve fitting related question as the next step to the above mentioned query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465934/dose-response-global-curve-fitting-using-r  Can you please advice me on how to fix the issue and proceed plotting the curves? - Thanks!