# Dose Response - Global curve fitting using R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have the following dose response data and wish to plot dose response model and global fit curve. [xdata = drug concentration; ydata(0-5) = response values at different concentrations of the drug]. I plotted the Std Curve without an issue.

**Std Curve Data fit:**

```
df <- data.frame(xdata = c(1000.00,300.00,100.00,30.00,10.00,3.00,1.00,0.30,
                           0.10,0.03,0.01,0.00),
                 ydata = c(91.8,95.3,100,123,203,620,1210,1520,1510,1520,1590,
                           1620))

nls.fit <- nls(ydata ~ (ymax*xdata / (ec50 + xdata)) + Ns*xdata + ymin, data=df,
               start=list(ymax=1624.75, ymin = 91.85, ec50 = 3, Ns = 0.2045514))
```

**Dose Response Curve Data fit:**

```
df <- data.frame(
        xdata = c(10000,5000,2500,1250,625,312.5,156.25,78.125,39.063,19.531,9.766,4.883,
                 2.441,1.221,0.610,0.305,0.153,0.076,0.038,0.019,0.010,0.005),
        ydata1 = c(97.147, 98.438, 96.471, 73.669, 60.942, 45.106, 1.260, 18.336, 9.951, 2.060, 
                   0.192, 0.492, -0.310, 0.591, 0.789, 0.075, 0.474, 0.278, 0.399, 0.217, 1.021, -1.263),
        ydata2 = c(116.127, 124.104, 110.091, 111.819, 118.274, 78.069, 52.807, 40.182, 26.862, 
                   15.464, 6.865, 3.385, 10.621, 0.299, 0.883, 0.717, 1.283, 0.555, 0.454, 1.192, 0.155, 1.245),
        ydata3 = c(108.410, 127.637, 96.471, 124.903, 136.536, 104.696, 74.890, 50.699, 47.494, 23.866, 
                   20.057, 10.434, 2.831, 2.261, 1.085, 0.399, 1.284, 0.045, 0.376, -0.157, 1.158, 0.281),
        ydata4 = c(107.281, 118.274, 99.051, 99.493, 104.019, 99.582, 87.462, 75.322, 47.393, 42.459, 
                   8.311, 23.155, 3.268, 5.494, 2.097, 2.757, 1.438, 0.655, 0.782, 1.128, 1.323, 0.645),
        ydata0 = c(109.455, 104.989, 101.665, 101.205, 108.410, 101.573, 119.375, 101.757, 65.660, 35.672, 
                   31.613, 12.323, 25.515, 17.283, 7.170, 2.771, 2.655, 0.491, 0.290, 0.535, 0.298, 0.106))
```

When I tried to get the fit parameters using the R script provided below, I get the following error:

**Error in nls(ydata1 ~ BOTTOM + (TOP - BOTTOM)/(1 + 10^((logEC50 - xdata) *  :

singular gradient**

```
nls.fit1 <- nls(ydata1 ~ BOTTOM + (TOP-BOTTOM)/(1+10**((logEC50-xdata)*hillSlope)), data=df,
                start=list(TOP = max(df$ydata1), BOTTOM = min(df$ydata1),hillSlope = 1.0, logEC50 = 4.310345e-08))

nls.fit2 <- nls(ydata2 ~ BOTTOM + (TOP-BOTTOM)/(1+10**((logEC50-xdata)*hillSlope)), data=df,
                start=list(TOP = max(df$ydata2), BOTTOM = min(df$ydata2),hillSlope = 1.0, logEC50 = 4.310345e-08))

nls.fit3 <- nls(ydata3 ~ BOTTOM + (TOP-BOTTOM)/(1+10**((logEC50-xdata)*hillSlope)), data=df,
                start=list(TOP = max(df$ydata3), BOTTOM = min(df$ydata3),hillSlope = 1.0, logEC50 = 4.310345e-08))

nls.fit4 <- nls(ydata4 ~ BOTTOM + (TOP-BOTTOM)/(1+10**((logEC50-xdata)*hillSlope)), data=df,
               start=list(TOP = max(df$ydata4), BOTTOM = min(df$ydata4),hillSlope = 1.0, logEC50 = 4.310345e-08))

nls.fit5 <- nls(ydata0 ~ BOTTOM + (TOP-BOTTOM)/(1+10**((logEC50-xdata)*hillSlope)), data=df,
                start=list(TOP = max(df$ydata0), BOTTOM = min(df$ydata0),hillSlope = 1.0, logEC50 = 4.310345e-08))
```

Please advice me on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that the ratio of the largest value of `xdata` to the smallest is 2 million so we likely want to use `log(xdata)` in place of `xdata`.

Now, making this change we get the 4 parameter log-logistic `LL2.4` model of the [drc package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drc) but with a slightly different parameterization than in the question.  Assuming that you are ok with these changes we can fit the first model as follows.  See  [?LL2.4](https://rdrr.io/cran/drc/man/LL.4.html) for the details of the parameterization and see the relevant examples at the bottom of [?ryegrass](https://rdrr.io/cran/drc/man/ryegrass.html) .  Here `df` is the `df` shown in the question -- the LL2.4 model itself makes the `log(xdata)` transformation.

```
library(drc)

fm1 <- drm(ydata1 ~ xdata, data = df, fct = LL2.4())
fm1
plot(fm1)
```

Here we fit all 5 models and visually we see from the plot at the end that the fits are pretty good.

```
library(drc)

fun <- function(yname) {
  fo <- as.formula(paste(yname, "~ xdata"))
  fit <- do.call("drm", list(fo, data = quote(df), fct = quote(LL2.4())))
  plot(fit)
  fit
}

par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
L <- Map(fun, names(df)[-1])
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

sapply(L, coef)
```

giving:

```
                     ydata1   ydata2   ydata3   ydata4   ydata0
    b:(Intercept)  -1.37395  -1.1411  -1.1337  -1.0633  -1.6525
    c:(Intercept)   0.70388   1.9364   1.5800   1.3751   5.7010
    d:(Intercept) 101.02741 122.0825 120.8042 108.2420 107.9106
    e:(Intercept)   6.17225   5.0686   4.3215   3.7139   3.2813
```

and the following graphical fits (click on the image to expand it):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `e` is  `log(EC50)`.  If you use `LL.4` (instead of `LL2.4`) then `e` will be EC50.  Please read the links provided.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for making my day. One quick probably dumb question. How would I interpret the fit data in terms of EC50 values? As I need EC50 values from all the 5 fits and use it to plot one more plot.  Should I calculate the EC50 from the fit values?

Comment: When I updated the xdata values with log values after adjusting for the concentration range [  xdata = c(-5.00, -5.30, -5.60, -5.90, -6.20, -6.51, -6.81, -7.11, -7.41, -7.71, -8.01,  -8.31, -8.61, -8.91, -9.21, -9.52, -9.82, -10.12, -10.42, -10.72, -11.02, -11.32)] I get  the following error:  Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

Comment: The code shown in the answer uses the `df` shown in the question and not some transformed version of it.  Please thoroughly read the links provided in the answer to fully understand the model..  The log transformation for xdata is done by the LL2.4 or LL.4 model, not by you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to G.Grothendieck's answer above for an overlay plot, just in case.

```
library(drc)
ys <- names(df)[-1]
for (i in 1:ys)  
 {fo <- as.formula(paste(ys[i], "~ xdata"))
  fit <- do.call("drm", list(fo, data = quote(df), fct = quote(LL2.4())))
    plot(fit, pch = 19+ x, ylim = c( min(df[,-1]),max(df[,-1])))
   par(new=TRUE)
  fit}
```

[image]